# Wireless driver for mouse movement on LInux/windows (with the help of interactive board)

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, usb, python

I have moved to mainly working on Linux machine primarily Ubuntu 15.04. Please the question here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/731546/wireless-driver-for-mouse-movement-on-ubuntu-15-04

---

I have a wireless board with genee powerboard http://www.genee-india.com/interactive-whiteboards/genee-powerboard/
I am trying to connect through dongle but with no success and support of it is not available.
But I can do it through a usb.

How do I make sure that the board is sending signals to my laptop.

The dongle is connected to COM2 port

[image]

and I have enabled COM2 port in the board settings.
[image]

The board shows this interface. It shows Board binded for 1 sec and then refreshes again. Also, what does the latter number of it mean? I am assuming it's some port number.
[image]

Edit 1:

## changed port later to COM30 from device manager

```
import serial
while True:
    ser=serial.Serial(port='COM30',baudrate=9600)
    print "try"
    s=ser.read(100) #reading up to 100 bytes
    print s
ser.close()
```

I tried to write a small program to read input from the board and then maybe possibly move the mouse. With the above program I get no input from the board. But I have no idea how drivers work, please let me know if I am doing something wrong. Do you need to intialise the board first?

Comment: Hmm. http://www.geneeworld.com/help-desk-support/ > 404. Not a good sign.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the vendor? https://www.geneeworld.com/interactive-whiteboard-support/ works.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah they say it only works for Windows XP. No further support.

Comment: Your question is a bit chaotic. I assuming that both screenshoots are form the board? How you displaying second screenshoot? What exactly is the dongle and how are you exactly connecting board to PC - USB/COM on board/PC site, serial or USB cable? You can monitor serial ports on Windows by Sysinternals PortMon, Free Serial Port Monitor or other software. I suggest you to start from monitoring transmission between board and XP machine. As serial connections might introduce additional complications I suggest to start from monitoring a TCP/UDP communication (NetBoard Params section).

Comment: [Free Serial Analyzer](http://freeserialanalyzer.com/) might help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that:

- Dongle is a serial to USB converter which you are connecting to your PC.
- You are connecting board by its COM2 through serial cable by "dongle" to laptop USB port assigned to COM2/COM30.

I don't know:

- Is "Config" and "board_driver" screenshots are taken from board or your PC?
- <s>Have you board have Ethernet port?</s> It is wireless - missed this.
- Is 192.168.0.127 a IP address of a board or a PC?
- What you mean by:

  > The board shows this interface. It shows Board binded for 1 sec and then refreshes again.

So now I try to help a little...

> How do I make sure that the board is sending signals to my laptop.
>
> I tried to write a small program to read input from the board and then maybe possibly move the mouse. With the above program I get no input from the board.
>
> Do you need to intialise the board first?

You can't assume that board ask first - the board can act as server/slave and wait for requests from client/master. Even if the board act as client/master you serial communication parameters (baud rate, data bit count, parity, stop bit count) have to be identical on both sides (board and PC).

You can monitor serial communication with:

- Sysinternals PortMon.
- HHD Software Free Serial Port Monitor / Free Serial Analyzer.
- Many other tools...

> Also, what does the latter number of it mean? I am assuming it's some port number.

If you mean 5000 it can be a IP port number - compare it with Config -> NetBoard Params -> Port.

> But I have no idea how drivers work, please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

You should try TCP/UDP connections first - Config -> NetBoard Params sugests that board listening on 192.168.0.127:5000 or will be trying to connect to 192.168.0.127:5000.

Helpful software:

- HWgroup Hercules SETUP utility.
- Wireshark.

IMO you should start from **monitoring functioning communication** of the board with a XP machine.

Comment: Anyway to work around without an XP machine?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia If you don't have a communication protocol documentation unfortunately I don't think so.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Argh... You can try XP Mode (officially on W7, unofficially on W8 too).

Comment: Can you explain more on procedure you mentioned. It will be greatly helpful!

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Which procedure? At least an up-vote will be very encouraging :P

Comment: Sorry I had looked at answer before and found very helpful but forgot in btw. I am talking about with "IMO you should start from monitoring functioning communication of the board with a XP machine." Please elucidate more on this.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Tell me what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Aren't you just trying to run this device on Windows 10?!?

Comment: I want to make run on debian version ultimately. It has driver ubuntu 9.10 but that does work either.

Comment: Maybe somehow read the cursor locations from the serial port and move the mouse. Getting the locations from port is what I am stuck at.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia How we going to do it? That's lot of informations - are you familiar with Sysinternals Suite or Wireshark? Before you start vivisecting a communication protocol you should try very hard to kindly ask protocol creator for its documentation - IMO even promising that you share your work is worth it! Have you prepared WinXP machine?